# Como puedo enlazar la DB y mi FTP a un html de mi localhost

Tags: base-de-datos, ftp, localhost

como están? quería hacer una pregunta sencilla, estoy en un dilema, necesito revisar la categorización de unos productos que están en la DB de mi empresa y me gustaría poder visualizar esos productos con imágenes en un HTML y así identificar mas rápido el tipo de producto por su imagen, nombre y categoría y hacer los cambios necesarios y poder subirlos bien categorizados.

Mi pregunta es:
como puedo enlazar los productos de la DB con las imagenes que tengo en el FTP y visualizarlo todo en un HTML de mi localhost? las imagenes tienen el sku de cada producto y los productos tienen su campo de imágenes y categoría.

Muchas gracias, se lo agradeceré toda la vida

Comment: La respuesta a la pregunta... si... puedes enlazarlos en la misma base de datos.

Comment: hola @Excorpion gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder, te digo... si.. sabia que se pueden enlazar, segundo párrafo de la publicación especifica mi pregunta..."como puedo enlazar la DB y el FTP a un HTML de mi localhost?"

Comment: Esa es una pregunta que no tiene cabida en SO español. Por favor mira [ask] para entender porqué.

Comment: cuarto punto de los ejemplos, cito:

Bien: ¿Cómo puedo redirigir a los usuarios a diferentes páginas basado en datos de la sesión en PHP?

https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

no es muy diferente a mi pregunta, se que debo usar php, se que si se puede, lo que no se es ¿como?

Comment: Eso es un titulo de ejemplo... para recibir ayuda debes demostrar que tienes algo y no que alguien más lo hará por ti. Por eso te puedo enviar a conectarte a ftp para partir en algo, pero seguro ya tienes eso.